# Why isnt my css class style not being applied to my component> @mui Container

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use a class style on a mui Container . Is that allowed ? i want the items inside the container for example to have a padding of 15px, it is not being applied to the elements inside at all. i want space between these input boxes. but i dont want to style every input box individually. Is there a way to style the parent Container and let it apply space between them ?

[image]

```js
const Search = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <Typography>Find a Vacation Kottage</Typography>
      <Container className={searchStyles.Container}>
        <TextField
          placeholder="Portland"
          label="Where do you want to go ?"
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="start">
                <LocationOnIcon />
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
          }}
        />
        <DatePicker
          disableFuture
          label="Check-in"
          openTo="day"
          views={["year", "month", "day"]}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            SettingsOverscanOutlined(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
        
      </Container>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

```css
.container{
    display: block;
    column-gap:20px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    justify-content:space-between
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I sa my error, the classname was lowercase .container, in my component head i was calling uppercase Container, silly me :)